# not able to change element on click in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

New to Javascript. Tried text type javascript also. Not worked. I doing this piece of code in notepad++ using html as extension and implementing on mozilla.

```html
<html>

<head></head>

<body>
  <h1>JavaScript in Body</h1>
  <p id="demo">A Paragraph.</p>
  <button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
  <script>
    function myFunction() {
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHtml = "Paragraph changed";
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: `.innerHTML`, "HTML" is all caps.

Answer (score 1):

`myFunction` is trying to call `innerHtml` but it should be `innerHTML` (HTML is capitalised).

`function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Paragraph changed";
}`

Answer (score 0):

You need to capitalize the `.innerHTML`: https://jsfiddle.net/1e091yo2/

```
function myFunction(){
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = 'See, I told you.'
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this working code.

```js
   

function myFunction() {
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML= "Paragraph changed";
    }
```

```html
   

<h1>JavaScript in Body</h1>
    <p id="demo">A Paragraph.</p>
    <button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
```